# eigenstates not eigenvectors of spin operator

Tags: quantum-spin

Ive been reading Griffiths's introduction to Quantum mechanics and just reached the chapter about spin. I really dont understand Griffiths's derivation of the eigenspinors of for instance $S_x$. This is supposed to be a very simple calculation, basically just calculating the eigenvectors to the following matrix:

$$S_x = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & \frac{h}{4\pi} \\
\frac{h}{4\pi} & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

When calculating the eigenvectors for this very simple matrix i get:
$$v_1 = 
\begin{pmatrix}
    1\\
 1
\end{pmatrix}$$
and
$$v_2 = \begin{pmatrix}
    -1\\
 1
\end{pmatrix}$$

This, however, seems to be the incorrect result. because Griffiths gets the same $v_1$ but
$$v_2 = \begin{pmatrix}
    1\\
 -1
\end{pmatrix}$$

I really don't understand this, because $v_2$ is not even an eigenvector to $S_x$. Letting Griffiths $v_2$ transform with $S_x$ should give a vector that is proportional to his $v_2$, but that ends up not happening. It's instead proportional to my $v_2$, and therefore $v_2$ can't be an eigenvector of $S_x$. I've obviously messed up somewhere, but I really don't see what it might be. I'd really appreciate some help. Thanks.

Comment: Note that if $\Lambda \vec v=\lambda \vec v$ for some operator $\Lambda$ and some eigenvector $\vec v$, then $\alpha \vec v$ is also an eigenvector $\forall \alpha\in \Bbb C-\{0\}$ (assuming your vector space is defined over $\Bbb C$ as is the case here)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

His $v_2$ and your $v_2$ simply differ by a $-1$ factor, so they're colinear. If one is an eigenvector of $S_x$, the other is too, for the same eigenvalue.

Comment: Ohh i see, that makes sense. Thanks for your answer, but why is that the normal convention for defining the eigenstate? Feels so unnatural

Comment: As far as I know, there is no convention. For a eigenvalue with multiplicity 1, the eigenvectors form a dimension-1 vector space, in other words they're all colinear. In quantum mechanics, the only important thing is that eigenvectors are usually normalized, which means that there are a infinite number of them, differing by a phase.